# Estimate probability of success and confidence intervals using R

Tags: r, dataframe, probability, confidence-interval, parametric-equations

[image]

So this table is from a file that I display using the R code: [read.csv()].

Question: I am now ask to estimate the probability of success using the parametric method and calculate its 95% confidence intervals using the exact method according to the age and then according to the sex (Male=1, female=2).

Attempts: For the parametric method using R I thought about binom.approx. Don't know if I am right and even how to do it.
For the exact method I guessed binom.confint(,,method="exact"). Again here how to code it.

Comment: From the data it would appear that logistic regression would be most appropriate.

Comment: @AllanCameron Okay then the probability of success would be written as a function of the age and/or sex. That is for example: `model1<-glm(Y~Age,family = binomial(link = logit), data=TBData1)`  . Now what about the exact method to get the the confidence interval from that probability of success?

Comment: Your regression would be more like `model1<-glm(Y~Age + factor(Sex), family = binomial(link = logit), data=TBData1)`. You would then get a prediction with confidence intervals by using `predict` at whatever values of `Age` and `Sex` you want.